# How does boson state operate on fermion state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I have a naive question on how Bosons interact with Fermions.

In quantum field theory, it is stated that the Fermions interact with each other by exchanging Bosons. That means, at a given time, a given Fermion state $\psi_f$ interacts with a Boson state $\psi_B$. My naive question is: is there a direct way to model the interaction between them? I mean: can we say something like: the Boson state operates on the Fermion state as: $\psi_f'\rightarrow{e^{i\psi_B}}\psi_f$?

I have seen [How does a boson interact with a fermion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576668/how-does-a-boson-interact-with-a-fermion) and I am not asking that question. My question is whether it is possible to conceive the interaction by such a direct method. I understand that $\psi_B$ may not be Hermitian.

Regards,
Kolahal

Comment: I don't think this statement is meant to be any deeper than that if you have a vertex in a Feynman diagram, an even number of legs need to be fermionic.

Comment: A single vertex in quantum field theory cannot in general maintain energy-momentum conservation. Therefore, the interaction of a single fermion with a single boson would not give a physical state. Perhaps you can reformulate the question so that it would be more physically reasonable.

Comment: Hello Jacob and Flippiefanus, thanks for your comments...I have not taken a formal course on QFT and may be talking rubbish. I reformulated the query in my reply to Robert's response. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe I'm wrong but I think the main constraint is that the interaction term must be a Lorentz-scalar.
Also its usually importamt that the system better be stable. So the intertaction term may not produce a wast amount of negative energy.
And linearity in the fields is a plus for the mathematics.

Your term does not seem to be Lorentz invariant.
Use gamma matrices to turn the spinor to Lorentz vector and  multiply it with a dual vector.

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you for pointing that out...May be I am talking vaguely, due to poor knowledge in QFT. But I am not thinking about an interaction term. Let me put the query in another way: suppose we have a non-relativistic particle $\psi_f$ that enters a region of potential V. We know how to write the Schr$\ddot{o}$dinger equation in this case. I am trying to see the same problem can be viewed in a different way: say, we know the wave function $\psi_B$ of the boson that underlies the potential V. In that case, can we say that the wave function $\psi_f$ undergoes an active transformation?

Comment: So you want an effective potential to represent a general bosonic field?

Comment: Hello, forgive my ignorance if it is not possible. I find it natural - let's say I have a charge in EM field. The force carriers in this field are the photons. Cannot we say that the photon $\psi_B$ operates on $\psi_F$ like the way I stated (I should mention that this idea stroke me as I am looking into the Aharonov-Bohm phase)?

Comment: Please, concretize the quesrion because I can't follow your thoughts. Anyway: you cannot represent a single photon by a scalar potential. In general case it seems pointless to me. In special cases - well find an interesting case.

Comment: Hello, okay, I'm sorry - may be my mistake...I will read more through the concepts and try to clarify it.